# ORA-09925 when login to Oracle in Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, oracle-database

I have installed Oracle 12c in my Manjaro PC, and i can't login because i got this error:

```
ORA-09925: Message 9925 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=ORA

Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory

Additional information: 9925

ORA-07446: Message 7446 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS,
facility=ORA; arguments: [oracle/product/db/rdbms/log] []
```

**init.ora**

```
db_name='ORCL'
memory_target=1G
processes = 150
audit_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/admin/oracle /adump'
audit_trail ='db'
db_block_size=8192
db_domain=''
db_recovery_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/fast_recovery_area'
db_recovery_file_dest_size=2G
diagnostic_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>'
dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLXDB)'
open_cursors=300 
remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
# You may want to ensure that control files are created on separate 
#physical devices
control_files = (ora_control1, ora_control2)
compatible ='11.2.0'
```

**.bashrc**

```
export ORACLE_BASE=oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=oracle/product/db
export ORACLE_INVENTORY=oracle/inventory
export ORACLE_SID=oracle
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export EDITOR=gedit
export VISUAL=gedit
```

Comment: If you don't find answers here; consider dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: `export ORACLE_HOME=oracle/product/db`  ... that shouldn't be a relative path, but an absolute one e.g. `export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/product/db`.

Comment: @StephenHarris still the same error.

Comment: ah sorry it's my fault i was thinking i already deleted it because i was advised to put it here.

Comment: And did you fix the init.ora file and so on?  The error you're seeing is a "Failed to create audit file" and the error message is reporting a relative path `oracle/product/db/rdbms/log`.   You must use absolute pathnames everywhere.

Comment: @Stephen, I'm sorry when i changed the `ORACLE_HOME` i forgot to logout and try again, when i did that now i can connect but when i try the command `startup` i got the `ORA-01078` and `LRM-00109`

Comment: Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/508514/edit) your question to reflect the point you are currently stuck at, adding the full text of the errors you are getting.

Comment: ORA-01078 means you have an error in your init.ora file.